# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind

Tags: java, weblogic, classnotfoundexception

When migrating our application from weblogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1 we run into the following stacktrace during deployment of our EAR:

```
<2018-06-05 16:17:03,765> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "518856605645758" for task "2" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I cannot find anything on the internet about this class and who might be using it, and so I have no clue how to solve this.

**Question:** Where does the afu.com.sun.* package come from, and how do I get rid of the dependency on this Tree class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by updating our dependency on Guava from 23.5-jre to 24.1-jre. This adds a transitive dependency to the checker framework that Cliffred mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

This is related to the checker framework (https://checkerframework.org/). You probably just need to add a dependency to your classpath: org.checkerframework:checker-qual, or org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual for Java 6 or 7.

Comment: The problem is actually the dependency on org.checkerframework:checker-qual (transitive via Guava). This dependency has classes that use afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind. Since checker-qual 2.1.0 this is not the case anymore. Guava 23.5-jre has a dependency on checker-qual 2.0.0, whereas Guava 24.1 has a dependency on checker-compat-qual 2.0.0. Later versions of Guava changed it back to checker-qual. And Guava 25.1 has the same problemen. But newer Guava versions use newer versions of checker-qual and therefore don't have this problem.